# How to delete all active geofences?

Tags: android, android-geofence

During development I've been testing with Geofences and initially added many geofences that had `.setExpirationDuration()` to indefinite (`NEVER_EXPIRE`). They performed some code in my Broadcast Receiver but I never deleted the actual geofences and I don't have their `requestid`.

How can I check if these Geofences are still active or not? I want to get rid of them to prevent them building up in memory.

The code is basically the same as the official Android tutorial: [Create and monitor Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

Code:

```
private fun createOnlineGeofence(currentLocation: GeoPoint){
    val geofenceId = randomAlphanumeric(10, 12)
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString("geofenceId", geofenceId)
        apply()
    }
    user.geofence = Geofence.Builder().apply {
        setRequestId(randomAlphanumeric(10, 12))
            setCircularRegion(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude, 400f)
            setExpirationDuration(28800000)
            setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            setNotificationResponsiveness(300000)
    }.build()
    val geofenceRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        addGeofence(user.geofence)
    }.build()
    val onlineGeofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(mContext.applicationContext, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("geofenceId", geofenceId)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Created online Geofence, geofenceId: ${user.geofence?.requestId}")
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofenceRequest, onlineGeofencePendingIntent)?.run {
            addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Online Geofence added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d(TAG, "Online geofence added")
            }
            addOnFailureListener {
                exception -> Log.d(TAG, "Exception: $exception")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no API provided by Google to check what geofences are active. All you can do is keep a list of active geofences on your side (sqlite or whatever) and deactivate them when needed.